# Which one of the properties of the ThemeData() class is related to changing the color of the app bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

we can edit default color of `scaffold` in all pages in app like this :

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red
      ),
    );
```

In this example, I changed the color of the scaffold with Property `scaffoldBackgroundColor:`. How can I do this for the app bar as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use appBarTheme property of ThemeData which is an [AppBarTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBarTheme-class.html) type

use it like this :

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBarTheme: [const] AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          // ...
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

add this dude:

```
return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          titleSpacing: 0,
          centerTitle: false,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontFamily: "NunitoBL",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
```